# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo este error,

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bancohdvdao\resources\views\aspirante\create.blade.php)

```
$aspirante = new Aspirante;
$correo = DB::table('users')->where('id', 'Auth::user()->id')->value('email');
return view('aspirante.create', ["aspirante" => $aspirante])->with('correo', 
$correo);
```

y el HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group row">
       <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Correo:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
             @foreach($correo as $correo)
             <input type="text" id="correoasp" class="form-control" name="correo_asp" value="{{$correo->email}}" placeholder="" disabled="disabled">
             @endforeach
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: lo que hago primero es tomar el campo id de la tabla users y después lo comparo con el id que se inicio sesión para así solo tomar el correo y después mostrarlo en una vista HTML.

Comment: Estas enviando desde tu controlador la variable `correo` pero en tu `foreach` usas `correos`, talvez hay esta tu error

Comment: amigo que pena, la letra "s" no va ahí, el código sigue con el mismo error..

Comment: Intenta cambiando la sintaxis de tu consulta, quitandole las comillas a Auth::user()->id, y utilizando el pluck, y no lo recorras con un foreach ya que si estas buscando por id deberia ser unico : $correo = DB::table('users')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('email');

Answer (score 0):

La variable correo no me queda claro si esperas que sea un array o un string. Tal y como la llamas declaras, debería ser un string ya que estas buscando que correo coincide con el id del usuario, y el id debe ser unico, luego solo debes obtener un único valor. Sin embargo, en la vista quieres recorrerla dentro del bucle, lo cual indica que debería ser un array u objeto.

Si quieres obtener varios correos no debes igualar en el metodo where el id a uno unico, sino a aquellos que quieras obtener. Aquí ya no se que condición buscas: todos los emails o ...¿?

Si solo quieres obtener el id del usuario, el foreach sobra.

Prueba también a quitar las comillas de 'Auth::user()->id'

Independientemente de que esto te solucione el error o no, sería mejor que llamaras a la variable que recorres en el foreach de otra forma:

```
foreach($correo as $data)
...
```

---

Yo lo haría así:

```
$aspirante = new Aspirante;
$correo = Users::find(Auth::user()->id)->email;
return view('aspirante.create', compact('aspirante','correo');
```

y en la vista:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group row">
       <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Correo:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
             <input type="text" id="correoasp" class="form-control" name="correo_asp" value="{{$correo}}" placeholder="" disabled="disabled">
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Por qué? Explícalo

Comment: Lo que quería hacer es obtener el correo del usuario logueado con la consulta que hice y ya lo hice. pero ahora al querer mostrar el correo en la vista me salio este error, Trying to get property 'email' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bancohdvdao\resources\views\aspirante\create.blade.php)

Comment: @shadow, lo va a confundir porque si quieres acceder a la variable original dentro de ese foreach no vas a poder. Sólo vas a poder acceder a cada uno de los elementos que componen a esa variable original.

Comment: quien lo va a confundir @cooper? si yo no he comentado nada

Comment: @SantiagoLMorales tu variable $correo ahora es una cadena de texto, luego para acceder a ella debes mostrarla asi (por ejemplo): {{$correo}}

Lo que te dice el error es que estas intentando acceder a una propiedad de algo que no es un objeto, y por eso te tira el error.

Comment: @cooper, Gracias!!! si al final lo entendí, para evitarme problemas lo que hice fue declarar un arreglo y en el guarde esa información, para que después el foreach en la vista pueda detectar el arreglo y poder mostrar los datos. no se, si hice bien...

Comment: @SantiagoLMorales por si te ayuda, he editado mi respuesta. Si la cambias, necesitaras incluir tu modelo de usuarios (use App\Models\User o donde lo tengas ubicado).