# Me salio este error en uno de los controladores en laravel. "Cannot use a scalar value as an array", ¿Como debo solucionarlo?

Tags: php, laravel

```
 $formacademica = new Formacademica;
 $userCorreo = Auth::user()->email;  

 $userCorreo = Auth::user()->email; /*Aqui solo capturo el usuario que ha iniciado sesión*/

 $aspirantes[] = DB::table('aspirantes')->where('correo_asp',$userCorreo)->first(); 
 /*en esta parte lo que hago es poner una condición con where, donde comparo el campo 
 correo_asp con la variable $userCorreo, para obtener los datos que tiene ese correo. Y es donde tengo el error*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, este tipo de error en PHP indica que se está usando una variable con un valor escalar (`string`, `float` o `integer`) como un arreglo. Cuando se intenta hacer esto, PHP envía un warning, esto lo puedes comprobar con la función `is_scalar` de PHP que permite conocer si una variable es escalar.

Según el código que ofreces, creo que al usar `$aspirantes[]` es cuando lanza esta excepción, antes debes comprobar que esta variable esté inicializada como un `array` o verificar que no esté creada anteriormente como una variable escalar.

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo de esta manera:

```
$userCorreo = Auth::user()->email;  

$userCorreo = Auth::user()->email;

$aspirantes = DB::table('aspirantes')->where('correo_asp',$userCorreo)->get();
```

en la vista lo recorres asi:

```
@foreach($aspirantes as $asp)
  {{$asp->correo_asp}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

¿para qué los corchetes?

Solo debería ser así

```
 $aspirantes = DB::table('aspirantes')->where('correo_asp',$userCorreo)->first();
```

La consulta que estas realizando solo retorna un objeto no un array, no es necesario usar un foreach

Ahora en la vista debes colocar algo como lo siguiente

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group row">           
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            @if($aspirantes)
                {{ $aspirantes->id_asp }}
            @endif
          </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Creo que te respondieron lo mismo en otra pregunta que realizaste

[Invalid argument supplied for foreach() con laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218474/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-con-laravel)

Comment: al no utilizar los corchetes, me sale un error común "Trying to get property 'id_asp' of non-object", y pasa cuando quiero mostrar los datos de la variable $aspirantes en una vista. por eso los utilizo, para que el foreach que es con el cual llamo a la variable me muestre los datos

Comment: puedes pasar el código de la vista? Ese error que mencionas es por que la consulta a la tabla no devolvió nada, creo que deberías colocar la validación en la vista de que si es objeto traiga el campo id_asp

Comment: No puedes usar foreach en una consulta que solo retorna un solo aspirante, ademas de eso estas usando ->first() que lo que hace es retornar el primer objeto. Modifique la respuesta con lo que debes usar en la vista.